# Facebook session logout using a different button in Facebook Web sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to logout of a facebook session using a different button? My website uses Login with Facebook feature and I want to destroy the logged in session of facebook using the different sign out button on my website. On signing out, I want to make the user log out of facebook as well. I have tried `session_destroy`, `setSession(null)` and several methods but I am not able to logout of facebook. Stuck up with this issue for several days and not able to find a solution.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/

Comment: yes already tried this one, but still no use. My website session gets destroyed but the facebook session is still live. On opening facebook on seperate tab, I am still logged in to my facebook account.